# Textarea and input have different widths

Tags: css, forms, cross-browser

CSS:

```
textarea, input {
  width:300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit">
```

Live Demo: http://codepen.io/qaz/pen/teaiG

Why do the input and textarea display with different widths? What properties do I need to add to make them the same width?

UPDATE:
By setting border and padding to 0px, I can make them display at the same width. Nobody wants padding:0px, though, and, strangely, when the padding is, say, 10px for both, they aren't the same width anymore. Now that I've found a solution with padding:0px, I'm still interested in an explanation and a solution that allows me still to have padding.

(I'm using Chrome 35 on Windows 7.)

Comment: Don't forgot to select an answer that you feel answered the question asked by selecting the **Green Checkbox** under the voting numbers by the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try setting it like this:

```
textarea, input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QV9PE/

The box-sizing CSS3 property can do just this. The border-box value (as opposed to the content-box default) makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box.

We can now safely declare our textarea to be of 300px width, including pixel-based padding and border, and accomplish out layout perfectly.

Comment: You were faster than me on this. Damn ipad! Anyway a quick explanation : this property brings back an old box model that included borders and padding in the width of the element, while current default box-model sums up the width of the element, the border width and the padding to get the final width of the element. Textareas are actually larger because of their default padding. Edit : damn even on the explanation you were faster :-)

Comment: Keyboard with 10 fingers is always faster than 2 thumbs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, I see this post is almost 10 years old.  I found a solution by setting both to width:100%.  This keeps them the same size.  Wrap them in a Div container and adjust the width of the container to the desired size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).